# jhipster with keycloak : error 401 not forwarded to login

Tags: oauth-2.0, jhipster, openid-connect, keycloak, http-status-code-401

I'm using Jhipster 4.13.3 with the Oauth2/OIDC option to generate a gateway connected keycloak.

When a service send a 401 status, redirection to /login doesn't executed.

An interceptor (auth-expired.interceptor.ts) is defined to handle the error, but it doesn't work correctly.

**First question**

In the if condition, error.json() doesn't contain path, so the condition is false and the redirection is never executed.

```
if (error.status === 401 && error.text() !== ''
                && error.json().path && !error.json().path.includes('/api/account')) {

            const destination = this.stateStorageService.getDestinationState();
            if (destination !== null) {
                const to = destination.destination;
                const toParams = destination.params;
                if (to.name === 'accessdenied') {
                    this.stateStorageService.storePreviousState(to.name, toParams);
                }
            } else {
                this.stateStorageService.storeUrl('/');
            }
            const loginService: LoginService = this.injector.get(LoginService);
            loginService.login();
        }
```

Somebody knows the correct condition ?

**Second question**

I disabled the check on "error.json().path...", the redirection is called but fails "often", it works sometimes, I didn't found a explanation. Even if I kill all sessions in the keycloak admin console, the browsers redirects to the home page, not the keycloak login form.

Does somebody have an explanation about this ?

Thanks,
Philippe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We kept getting HTTP 401 status code responses when the hostname stamped on the iss field of the bearer's/user's access token had a different case i.e. lowercase vs. uppercase than the hostname in the URL used to post an HTTP request to keycloak's token endpoint.

Any kind of hostname mismatch can cause 401 errors:

- Short hostname alias vs. fully qualified hostname e.g. https://myhost:8080 vs. https://myhost.domain.com:8080
- https://MYHOST:8080 vs. https://myhost:8080
- https://Myhost:8080 vs. https://myhost:8080
- etc.

This happened in a Microsoft Windows 10 version 1809 environment.